# questions about connected and Hausdorff topological Space

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

**1:** let $X$ be a Hausdorff topological  Space , $Y \subseteq X $ is Nonempty and dense in $X$.
let $f: X \longrightarrow X $ be a continuous functions so that $ \forall y \in Y, f(y) = y $.

> **Is $f$ a  identical function?**

*My second question is:*

**2:** Let $A$ be a connected subset of  the topological space $X$and $Y \subseteq X $.

> Can we say if $A \bigcap Y \neq \emptyset$ and $A \bigcap Y^{c}\neq \emptyset$, then $ A \bigcap \partial Y  \neq \emptyset $? Why?

Comment: Y⊆X is Nonsense?  I can't even guess what this is supposed to say.

Comment: As asked in a previous comment, can you please define what $Y\subset X$ is "nonsense" means?

Comment: @Nico the edit shows it means "non-empty and dense".

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, you should upvote all the useful answers and accept the answer that is most useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes to the second one, because for any $Y \subseteq X$, the three sets
$\operatorname{int}(Y), \partial Y, \operatorname{int}(Y^c)$ are pairwise disjoint and partition $X$. If $A$ were to miss $\partial Y$ the other two open sets would disconnect $A$, which cannot be.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "Nonsense", but $\{x\in X: f(x)=x\}$ is closed in $X$, so if it is dense it must be the whole space.